# Combobox vir em branco VB.NET com INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Estou com o probleminha aqui e não encontrei a solução ainda, estou carregando dados em um combobox usando um **DATASET** a partir de um **INNER JOIN** feito em um banco de dados **SQL SERVER**. Até então tudo bem só que assim que buscar a cong, gostaria que o outro combobox ficasse em branco...

> Já tentei colocar meucbx.SelectedIndex = 0 no Load, não obtive exito

### Segue meu código

```
//Listar as Congs listar_Cong vai para o Load


Private Sub listar_Cong()
        Using con As SqlConnection = CONECTA_DB()
            Try
                con.Open()
                Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM sys_Config WHERE Status = 1"
                Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, con)
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While dr.Read
                    cbxCong.Items.Add(dr.Item("Nome")).ToString()
                End While
            Catch
               msgbox(Err.description)
            Finally
                con.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub

   //Lista os usuarios com o INNER JOIN

  Private Sub listar_USUARIOS()
        Using con As SqlConnection = CONECTA_DB()
            Try
                con.Open()
                Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM sys_Config" _
                                    & " INNER JOIN sys_Users"_
                                    & " ON (sys_Config .ID_CONG = sys_Users .ID_CONG)" _
                                    & " WHERE sys_Users.Status = 1"
                Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(str, con)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                da.Fill(ds)
                With cbxUsuarios
                    .DisplayMember = "Usuario"
                    .ValueMember = "ID_CONG"
                    .DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
                End With
            Catch
                MessageBox.Show(Err.Description)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: O que é `cong`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera consegui resolver aqui esta com um erro bloco de código no meu sistema.
Agradeço pelas tentativas!

`//Era simplesmente locar isso
cbxUsuarios.SelectedIndex = 0
//só que eles estava no local errado`

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer apenas limpar o `ComboBox`:

```
meucbx.Items.Clear()
```

Comment: Depois do usuario selecionar o cong ele vir com o combobox em branco sem nada selecionado... Cong é congregação

Comment: E esse código não resolveu?

Comment: Com aquele código ali eu zero todos os dados do combo.. gostaria que o index no inicio fosse 0 mais se eu coloca no load não funciona depois de solicitar busca.. ele da problema.. tipo o usuario seleciona a congregação ele ja vai e seleciona o usuario automatico